# Change date to String format

Tags: react-native

I need to send a date(ISO) to server from my file(React-native). But backend(node.js) accepts a date in string format.

Date in UI => 2021-02-10T13:01:00.000Z.

Expected Date format in backend is => "2021-02-10T13:01:00.000Z"

I tried date.toString() method. It changes the format of date like **Wed Feb 03 2021 16:46:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)** this.

Is there any other JS method to change the typeOf date.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have a try with new Date().toISOString() it will give us string date in ISO format

Comment: Tried that already. Its also not working

Comment: We also can try by adding the npm package of "moment"
it will provide you a lot of functionality to manage the date formats and extract a particular date format from the whole date.

for ex. 
moment().toISOString() // 2013-02-04T22:44:30.652Z

check-out the doc for more options:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment : [moment documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "moment" package to format date.

```
import moment from "moment";
moment(date,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",true).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
```